# Why do I still have this module error not found despite the module being present?

Tags: python, linux

I just want to ask why i still keep getting this module error not found in a linux machine. I asked chatgpt to help me install autogpt and give me the codes but we've been going in circle ever since, stating i uninstall reinstall it.

daniel@ERPNEXT:~$ source myenv/bin/activate
(myenv) daniel@ERPNEXT:~$ pip list
Package                  Version
------------------------ ----------
*autogpt                  0.0.1.dev0*
cmake                    3.26.3
distlib                  0.3.6
filelock                 3.12.0
Jinja2                   3.1.2
lit                      16.0.2
MarkupSafe               2.1.2
mpmath                   1.3.0
networkx                 3.1
nvidia-cublas-cu11       11.10.3.66
nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu11   11.7.101
nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu11   11.7.99
nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu11 11.7.99
nvidia-cudnn-cu11        8.5.0.96
nvidia-cufft-cu11        10.9.0.58
nvidia-curand-cu11       10.2.10.91
nvidia-cusolver-cu11     11.4.0.1
nvidia-cusparse-cu11     11.7.4.91
nvidia-nccl-cu11         2.14.3
nvidia-nvtx-cu11         11.7.91
pbr                      5.11.1
pip                      23.1.2
platformdirs             3.5.1
setuptools               59.6.0
stevedore                5.0.0
sympy                    1.11.1
torch                    2.0.0
triton                   2.0.0
typing_extensions        4.5.0
virtualenv               20.23.0
virtualenv-clone         0.5.7
virtualenvwrapper        4.8.4
wheel                    0.40.0
(myenv) daniel@ERPNEXT:~$ pip show autogpt
Name: autogpt
Version: 0.0.1.dev0
Summary: autogpt
Home-page: 
Author: Shadow Walker
Author-email: 
License: 
Location: /home/daniel/myenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages
Requires: torch
Required-by: 
(myenv) daniel@ERPNEXT:~$ python test_autogpt.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/daniel/test_autogpt.py", line 1, in 
import autogpt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'autogpt'

the content of the python script "test_autogpt.py" only containd this:
import autogpt

print(autogpt.**version**)

any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

chat-gpt codes but it still going in circles

Comment: Are you running python2 or python3?  What happens with **python3 -m autogpt**

Comment: it shows this:

(myenv) daniel@ERPNEXT:~$ python --version

Python 3.10.7

(myenv) daniel@ERPNEXT:~$ python3 --version

Python 3.10.7

(myenv) daniel@ERPNEXT:~$ python3 -m autogpt

/home/daniel/myenv/bin/python3: No module named autogpt

Comment: Have you checked for other modules whether you have the same problem. Check also sys.path to see where the modules are searched.

Comment: @EricMarchand typing this python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)" gave me this:   <br/>
['', '/usr/lib/python310.zip', '/usr/lib/python310', '/usr/lib/python310/lib-dynload', 'home/daniel/myenv/lib/pyhton3.10/site-packages']

Comment: @EricMarchand i tried the cmake module, right after the autogpt, and it works. same code, i just used import and print